# Unknown SQL syntax error PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
try {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO order(
                user_id,
                departure_street,
                departure_housenr,
                departure_postalcode,
                departure_city,
                arrival_street,
                arrival_housenr,
                arrival_postalcode,
                arrival_city,
                order_date,
                lifter,
                order_status
            ) 
            VALUES(
                :user_id,
                :departure_street,
                :departure_housenr,
                :departure_postalcode,
                :departure_city,
                :arrival_street,
                :arrival_housenr,
                :arrival_postalcode,
                :arrival_city,
                :order_date,
                :lifter,
                :order_status
            )";

    $stmt = $dbh -> get_instance() -> prepare( $sql );

    $stmt -> execute( array( ':user_id' => $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ],
                             ':departure_street' => $street1_parsed, 
                             ':departure_housenr' => $streetnumber1,
                             ':departure_postalcode' => $postcode1, 
                             ':departure_city' => $city1_parsed,
                             ':arrival_street' => $street2_parsed,
                             ':arrival_housenr' => $streetnumber2, 
                             ':arrival_postalcode' => $postcode2, 
                             ':arrival_city' => $city1_parsed,
                             ':order_date' => $datetime,
                             ':lifter' => $lifter,
                             ':order_status' => $order_status ) );

}
catch( PDOException $e ) {

    echo $e -> getMessage() . '<br />' . $sql;

}
```

This code keeps giving me this **error:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'order(
>           user_id,
>         departure_street,   ' at line 1

I don't understand what can be wrong with the syntax. I've used this query so many times and it always works. What's the problem now? I've tried to `echo` the `$sql` variable to see what the resulting query looks like, but it doesn't show me the values that are being inserted. Can anyone see the SQL syntax error?

Comment: order is a reserved word in mysql so wrap that inside `` (backticks)

Comment: are you print your `query`???

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Damn, this is the second time a reserved SQL keyword screws me up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER` is mysql key word .it should be enclosed by backticks .if your table name or column name is key word just use backticks  **`order`**   backticks ``

[here you can find the mysql keywords list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes (SO logic) :/